# keyboard taping sound is not coming from the DetectableTextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on one video & audio player application and at one point i found that keyboard tap sound is not working in my application and in other apps and in system app keyboard tap sound is coming well.

I have find a solution lot but i think this thing doesn't happened to anyone so i raised a question here

```
DetectableTextField(
                        decoratedStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: fNSfUiBold,
                          letterSpacing: 0.6,
                          fontSize: 13,
                        ),
                        basicStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: fNSfUiRegular,
                          letterSpacing: 0.6,
                          fontSize: 13,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        inputFormatters: [
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(175),
                        ],
                        enableSuggestions: false,
                        maxLines: 8,
                        cursorColor: colorTextLight,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          textSize.value = value.length;
                          postDes = value;
                        },
                        onDetectionTyped: (text) {
                          currentHashTag = text.split("#")[1];
                        },
                        onDetectionFinished: () {
                          if (currentHashTag.isNotEmpty) {
                            hashTags.add(currentHashTag);
                            currentHashTag = '';
                          }
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          hintText: 'Add a caption and tags',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: colorTextLight,
                          ),
                        ),
                        detectionRegExp: detectionRegExp(hashtag: true)!,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences
                      )
```

Please help me to get out of this issue.